# background won't display for div

Tags: html, css, background

Currently I am trying to give a class a background image and make it repeat vertically.

Im using the following code for the image:

```
background: url('http://ponyterrance.co.uk/gmod-loadingscreen/main.png') repeat-y;
```

I have also tried

```
background-image: url('http://ponyterrance.co.uk/gmod-loadingscreen/main.png') repeat-y;
```

But I got nothing from this. The page in question can be seen here: http://ponyterrance.co.uk/gmod-loadingscreen/arkonn.html if you want a better idea of what I mean

Its rather irritating because I used the exact same code on the background of a div on a page I made 4 hours ago. I can't see anything wrong though. I've looked over it for a while now looking for anything being missing but it appears all there. You lot will probably see it straight away but I'm blind as hell.

Also I have tried http linking the file as well as just 'main.png' as its in the same directory.

JSFIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/tejashsoni111/U5CLS/

Comment: can u post it on fiddle

Comment: have you tried z-index?

Comment: Also, please don't fry me for not linking my stylesheets. I build it all together then link it after.

I'll upload a fiddle now

Comment: It's not a backgorund image at all...it's inline HTML (`<img src="http://ponyterrance.co.uk/gmod-loadingscreen/logo1.png" style="width: 800px; height: 103px;">`

Comment: 1) Thats not the element I am trying to change. I should have specified its the background image of the class 'content'

2) Heres fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Te8Cn/

Comment: The dimension of your image is 2000*43.. and the size of ur content #main .content width: 849px;height: 697px; it wont display

Comment: change the dimension of your image to a smaller one it will work !! :)

Comment: Well explain why it works here: http://ponyterrance.co.uk/gmod-loadingscreen/index.php?steamid=%s&mapname=%m

Comment: The issue is with the image you are using, not the code itself (I placed a different image url into the property in inspector and it worked fine).

Comment: My bad!! I forgot background-size.   I'm so retarded. Quite literally. Works now http://ponyterrance.co.uk/gmod-loadingscreen/arkonn.html

Comment: he has added background size as 1000px so it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add background size to the image you are using else reduce the size of the image to the container dimension.

Comment: Your previous comment 'change the dimension of your image to a smaller one it will work !! :)' made me think 'size'. Thanks :) - Will mark this as solution

Answer (score 0):

Your div is small and part of image that covers div is white hence not visible. Use colored image or change size of div to see full image.

Answer (score 0):

is the div empty ? if so have you tried putting a non-zero value to width and height?

```
width: /* != 0 value here */ ;
height: /* != 0 value here */ ;
```

maybe try moving the repeat as seperatly

```
background-repeat:repeat-y;
```

if any more ideas will pop-up into my head i'll update the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use the below style, it will work

```
#main .content {
background-image: url("http://ponyterrance.co.uk/gmod-loadingscreen/main.png");
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this without height and width,

```
#main .content {
  background: url('http://ponyterrance.co.uk/gmod-loadingscreen/main.png') repeat-y 0 0;
  overflow:hidden; 
}
```